# Error installing Google OR-Tools in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, 64-bit, or-tools

I am trying to install the OR tools using this command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --user ortools
```

The reponse of the command line is the following:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ortools (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for ortools

I **already installed the 64 bit python** version 3.8 for Windows, but that did not seem to be the problem.

What can I do to install the ORtools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3.8 is too new.

You will need to wait for the next release or downgrade to python 3.7 for now. (I do not recommend install from source on windows)

See: [issue at github](https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1702)

```
lperron commented on Nov 9
[...] should be next release.

CURRENT release:

v7.4 (2019-10)
lperron released this on Oct 11 · 143 commits to master since this release

Python 3.8 was released on October 14th, 2019.
```